# Emailing when submit button is pressed

Tags: php, email, send

```
<?php
 echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')) 
 $to = "someone@hotmail.com"; $subject = "Test mail";
 $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
 $from = "someonelse@example.com";
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Hey guys need help here! I want when someone pressed the submit button, it saves and sends the details entered to the emails

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: me, I want a dog for my birthday

Comment: if it is not working... i am sure you will have an error... so post that error too ..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this.Make sure your button type is submit

```
<?php
if($_POST){

    $to = "someone@hotmail.com"; $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "someonelse@example.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";


    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what email should i put in $from?

Comment: From email notifies that who is sending this mail.Use any of yours for testing.If you don't provide email may go to spam

Comment: i mean like, when you are sending an email you need to provide like who is sending the email. but we didnt provide any of that arent we? im not really clear like what will be written in the email as the sender? REally sorry, still new in php stuffs :(

Comment: I you have a live website then obviously it will be you who is sending emails.For example if you gat email from facebook it will clearly show that it is sent by facebook

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // check if submit button is pressed
        $to = "someone@hotmail.com"; $subject = "Test mail";
        $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
        $from = "someonelse@example.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
           echo "Mail Sent.";
        else
           echo 'Error while sending mail.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still running WAMPServer then you are on a Windows PC.

Window does not come with a mail server, and the `mail()` function does little else other than pass a mail onto a mail server.

You will either need to install a mail server, they do exist for windows, but this is not a simple task for a beginner.

Alternatively, look at `phpMailer` which can be used to send mail and basically piggy backs an existing email account like one of your yahoo or gmail accounts