# How to get php render HTML result as the content of email

Tags: php, email

Hi I am developing a shopping cart.I need to know to how to send php code as email to customer.When a customer clicks the 'order now' button, a page has to be displayed showing all the products purchased by him and an email should be sent automatically to the customer's mail id detailing about the products he purchased.My problem is that I don't know to write the code for sending email.Anyone can you please help me? 
Here is my code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('head.php');
?>
<?php
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $pmode=$_POST['pmode'];

    $query="INSERT INTO  customer(customer_first_name,customer_last_name,customer_email,customer_phone,payment_type)VALUES('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','$phone','".$pmode."')";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
?>
<html>
    <center><font color="#493D26"><b><?php echo "Welcome $fname";?></b><font></center><br><br>
    <center><font color="#151B54"><b><?php echo "You have successfully registered";?></b></font></center>
    <?php
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    ?>
    <form name="orderform" action="pdtorder.php" method="post">
        <table align="center" width="750" height="300">
            <tr><td> First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>  Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>  Email id :</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>  Phone Number :</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Payment Mode : </td>
            <?php
                if($pmode=='money'){
            ?>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Money Transfer</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="money" checked/></td>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Bank Transfer</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="bank"/></td>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Credit Card</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="credit"/></td></tr>
            <?php
                }
                if($pmode=='bank'){
            ?>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Money Transfer</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="money" /></td>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Bank Transfer</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="bank" checked/></td>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Credit Card</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="credit"/></td></tr>
            <?php
                }
                if($pmode=='credit'){
            ?>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Money Transfer</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="money" /></td>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Bank Transfer</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="bank" /></td>
                <td><font color="#0000A0"><b>Credit Card</b></font><input type="radio" name="pmode" value="credit" checked/></td></tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <h4>You have ordered</h4>
        <table id="mytable" width="50%" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="3px">
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $count=0;
            foreach( $_SESSION['r'] as $key=>$ar):
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>">
                <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Name']?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <select class="myclass" name="qty" id='<?php echo $Identifier;?>' >
                        <?php
                            for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
                                $y="";
                                if( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']){
                                    $y="selected";
                                }
                                echo "<option ";
                                echo "value=\"$i\" ".$y.">", $i, "</option>\n";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <?php $x=$x+$ar['Quantity']; ?>
                <td name="price"><?php echo $ar['Total']; ?></span></td>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' id="pid_<?php echo $Identifier;?>" value='<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>'>
                <input type='hidden' name='price' id="price_<?php echo $Identifier;?>" value='<?php echo $ar['Price'] ?>' class="input">
                <?php $tt[]=$ar['Total']; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $cnt++;
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </table>
        <?php
            foreach($tt as $t){
                $count=$count+$t;
            }
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <table>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr><b><font color="B048B5">Grand Total :</font><?php echo $count; ?></b><span id="GrandTotal"></span></tr>
            <b><!--<font color="#F6358A">Your Cart:--></font></b>
            <div align="center" id="cart"><?php echo $x; ?> </div>
            <center><img src="upload/images.jpeg" width="100"></center>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="order" value="Order Now" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hemail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    </form>
</html>
<?php
}else{
    die(mysql_error());
}
?>
</html>
```

When I click on the 'Order now ' button, I need to send the $_SESSION['r'] as the content to customer's mail id.How can I do it? As I need to send many products details I need to use a for each loop and then send as email content.How can I do it?

Comment: `mail($to, $subject, $message)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emailing when submit button is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072046/emailing-when-submit-button-is-pressed)

Comment: but what will I put $message??I don't know how to append $_SESSION['r'] as my $message.Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `singleItem` to store each item html
2. print the `singleItem` after the html is prepared
3. append `singleItem` into `orderItemDetail` in foreach loop
4. use the `orderItemDetail` in your mailing function

Detail code:

```
<?php
    $orderItemDetail = '';
    $count=0;
    foreach( $_SESSION['r'] as $key=>$ar):
        $x=$x+$ar['Quantity'];
        $tt[]=$ar['Total'];
        $singleItem = ''; // (1)

        $singleItem .= "<tr id='{$ar['Id']}'>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<td align='center'>{$ar['Name']}</td>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<td align='center'>{$ar['Price']}</td>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<td align='center'>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<select class='myclass' name='qty' id='{$Identifier}' >\n";
        for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
            $singleItem .="<option value='{$i}' " . (( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']) ? 'selected' : '') . ">{$i}</option>\n";
        }
        $singleItem .= "</select>\n";
        $singleItem .= "</td>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<td name='price'>{$ar['Total']}</td>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<input type='hidden' name='id' id='pid_{$Identifier}' value='{$ar['Id']}'>\n";
        $singleItem .= "<input type='hidden' name='price' id='price_{$Identifier}' value='{$ar['Price']}' class='input'>\n";
        $singleItem .= "</tr>\n";

        $orderItemDetail .= $singleItem; //(2)
        print($singleItem); //(3)
        $cnt++;
    endforeach;

    $message .= $orderItemDetail; //(4)
?>
```